# Preserve padding while setting an axis limit

Tags: python, matplotlib

Setting xlim and ylim for axis in pyplot removes the padding. How to set them without changing the padding?

Example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0, 200, 500)
ax.set_ylim(ymax=100)
line = ax.plot(x, data, '--', linewidth=2, label='foo bar')
plt.show()
```

In the plot shown, x axis will have a padding while y axis don't. How to make them both have padding while having the ylim I want?

Answer (score 22):

`Axes.set_ymargin` and `Axes.set_ylim` are mutually exclusive. Setting a limit to an axis overwrites the margin.

There are two options to have a margin (padding).

#### a. use margins

It's possible to adapt the margin using

```
ax.set_ymargin(0.1)   or   ax.margins(y=0.1)
```

where `0.1` would be a 10% margin on both axis ends. (Same for `x` axis of course). The drawback here is that the margin is always symmetric.

#### b. use limits

Using the limits set by `ax.set_ylim(0, 100)` and adapt them to the needs.
E.g. if `data` is the data to plot in form of a numpy array, and we want to have a 10% margin to the bottom and a 40% margin to the top, we could use

```
ymin = data.min()-0.1*(data.max()-data.min())
ymax = data.max()+0.4*(data.max()-data.min())
ax.set_ylim((ymin, ymax))
```

It would of course equally be possible to simply set ymax to `ymax = 100`, if this is desired.

Comment: This works, but it of course display a maximum that may not make sense. For example, I have set my ylimits at 95% to 100%. 105% in my case would not make sense. Can this be avoided? Basically as in the original question, I simply want 5% margins for example top and bottom.

Comment: Is there a possibility to express the margins as fixed values rather than a percent of the figure size?

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the `ax.dataLim` bounding box and reapply `ax.autoscale_view()`

Before:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
line = ax.plot(x, x, '--', linewidth=2, label='foo bar')
```

[image: Before]

After:

```
ax.dataLim.y1 = 11  # new ymax
ax.autoscale_view()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer and deserves way more upvotes! Can I suggest `ax.dataLim.y1 = 11` as a simpler alternative to the first three lines in the second code snippet? One can analogously tweak x0, x1 and y0.

Comment: Thanks, @dlukes ! I was not aware of the additional attributes x0, x1, y0, y1, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax. That certainly simplifies it a great deal.

Comment: One small nitpick -- the x/y min/max attributes aren't actually settable (presumably because it's valid in some cases to flip e.g. x0 and x1 so that x1 is actually the smaller value, and xmin is always guaranteed to return the smallest of the two, so it's read-only?). So `ax.dataLim.ymax = 11` doesn't work (at least not in my case -- it raises `AttributeError: can't set attribute 'ymin'`), whereas `ax.dataLim.y1 = 11` does. (I also tried using the x/y min/max attributes first, as the names felt more descriptive :) )

Comment: Good catch. Thought I had checked that.

Answer (score 2):

With matplotlib 3.5, I used autoscaling as follows;

```
axs[row,column].plot(divs['Dividends'], c='red',linewidth=1, marker='.', mec='blue',mfc='blue')
axs[row,column].set_ylim(bottom = 0)        
axs[row,column].autoscale()
```

Solved this problem for me. See attached pics of the graphs for the difference autoscaling did.

Using .margins() with a value or 'tight=True' or .set_ymargin() didn't seem to do anything no matter what values I used to pad.

Changing the lower or bottom limit to <0 moved the Zero line well up the y axis when dividends in my examples are close to zero.

[Graph with Autoscaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zybpS.png)

[Graph without Autoscaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Z3C.png)